# Stack select box and button under each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I would like this select box and button to stay centered and stacked under each other when the window is resized(but to stay like this in full window). However, I got stuck in Bootstrap classes and as you can see in the example it does not work as supposed.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLJYPj

EDIT: SOLVED - I came up with this solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYRPgv

Any ideas how to make it work?

```css
.search {
 background: url("../img/pattern.png");
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 215px;
}

.search__region {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa url("../img/arrowdown.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.search__region select {
    padding: 10px 18px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 130%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.input-group {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.search__region--button {
 padding: 16px 0px;
 background-color: green;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container search">
 <div class="input-group">
  <div class="search__region pull-left">
    <select>
      <option value="">Search something</option>
      <option value="">One</option>
      <option value="">Two</option>
      <option value="">Three</option>
    </select>

 </div>

  <div class="search__button pull-right">
   <button class="search__region--button">Button</button>
  </div>
 </div>

</div> <!-- end search container -->
```

Comment: Is your problem solved

Comment: @AnujaAgarwal yes, I came up with this solution, thanks for the advices: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYRPgv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I came up with - link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oYRPgv

```
.search {
  background: url("../img/pattern.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.search h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.search__content {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

.search__region {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fafafa url("../img/arrowdown.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}

.search__region select {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search__region select .option {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  width: 100%;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

@media screen and(max-width: 768px) {
  .search h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
  }
  .search__content {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  .search__content .search__region {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .search__content .search__region--button {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.search__region--button {
  padding: 16px 0px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

<div class="container search">
  <div class="search__content">
    <div class="search__region">
      <select>
                <option value="" class="option">Choose something</option>
                <option value="" class="option">One</option>
                <option value="" class="option">Two</option>
                <option value="" class="option">Three</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <button class="search__region--button">button</button>
  </div>
  <!-- end search__content -->
</div>
<!-- end search container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.pull-left` and `.pull-right`

Comment: yes but now they are not next to each other in full window

Comment: `.search__region { margin: 0 auto;}`

Comment: sorry maybe now I was not clear, I need the select and button to be next to each other in full window(see here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLJYPj ), but stacked under each other only when I reduce window size, and stay centered

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex;` on `.input-group` , and some small changes to your style. you can vary the button's width, currently set on `100%`.

here's the working code.

```css
.search {
 background: url("../img/pattern.png");
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 215px;
}

.search__region {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa url("../img/arrowdown.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
/*     margin-right: 30px; */
}

.search__region select {
    padding: 10px 18px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 130%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.input-group {
 margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  width:250px;
}

.search__region--button {
 padding:16px 0px;
 background-color: green;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container search">
 <div class="input-group">
  <div class="search__region pull-left">
    <select>
      <option value="">Search something</option>
      <option value="">One</option>
      <option value="">Two</option>
      <option value="">Three</option>
    </select>

 </div>

  <div class="search__button pull-right">
   <button class="search__region--button">Button</button>
  </div>
 </div>

</div> <!-- end search container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .search {
 background: url("../img/pattern.png");
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 215px;
}

.search__region {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fafafa url("../img/arrowdown.png") no-repeat 90% 50%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom : 10px; 
}

.search__region select {
    padding: 10px 18px;
    height: 55px;
    width: 130%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.input-group {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.search__region--button {
 padding: 16px 0px;
 background-color: green;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container search">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="input-group">
  <div class="search__region ">
    <select>
      <option value="">Search something</option>
      <option value="">One</option>
      <option value="">Two</option>
      <option value="">Three</option>
    </select>

 </div>
 </div></div>

 
 <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="search__button ">
   <button class="search__region--button">Button</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end search container -->
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You show be follow this code because you are using bootstrap

```css
.search__region select {
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 55px!important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
}

.search__region--button {
    padding: 16px 0px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
}

.dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -1px;
    padding: 6px 20px;
}

.input-group-btn .btn-group {
    display: flex !important;
}

.btn-group .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.btn-group .btn:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group .form-horizontal .btn[type="submit"] {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.form-group .form-control:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #adv-search {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg {
        position: static !important;
    }
    .dropdown.dropdown-lg .dropdown-menu {
        min-width: 500px;
    }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
                <div class="search__region">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Search something</option>
                        <option value="">One</option>
                        <option value="">Two</option>
                        <option value="">Three</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <div class="search__button pull-right">
                            <button class="search__region--button">Button</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```